# Number plate recognition

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am planning to perform OCR on Indian number plates. I used Tesseract 4.0 beta, which uses LSTM engine for OCR. Although recognized characters are not coming out to be correct.

I used `cv2.Laplacian()` while picking up images without blur and performed noise reduction using `cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored()` on the image.

```
file_path = '/home/aayush/Downloads/Vision/number_plates/'
image_path = sorted(list(paths.list_images(file_path)))
#load image
for image in image_path:
 img = cv2.imread(image)
 img = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,10,10,7,21)
 #test 1
 #sharpen the image
 kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
 img = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)
 #thresholding
 ret,img_th = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
 #invert image
 inv_img = cv2.bitwise_not(img_th)
 config = ('-l eng --oem 1 --psm 6')

 #dilating image :
 kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
 erosion = cv2.erode(inv_img,kernel,iterations = 1)
 text = pytesseract.image_to_string(inv_img, config=config)
 print(text)
 cv2.putText(img,text,(20,20),0, 5e-3 * 200, (255,255,255),2)
 cv2.imshow("Image:",inv_img)
 if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For preprocessing I performed the following steps:

1. Sharpened image
2. Applied Otsu thresholding
3. Eliminated smaller noises/contours
4. Inverted image
5. OCR using Tesseract 4.0 --oem 1 (which uses LSTM as detection module)

[image: Orignal image]

[image: otsu thresholded image]

[image: Contour removed image]

Detected output:
`OL 1CT 5079`
(Which seems ok)

Can you please suggest any other preprocessing required to improve the image (reduce noise)?

Also is there a way to restrict special characters in Tesseract?

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example of your code.

Comment: Tesseract is trained on sample data. In the case of number plates, different countries use different fonts. Your input image is low resolution and slightly blurry, and I assume it's representative of the data you want to process. For better results, you might need to use datafiles trained specifically for Indian number plates. Check out [openalpr](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/tree/master/runtime_data/ocr/tessdata), for example.

Comment: Many countries do not use certain letters at all in number plates , because they are easily confused with digits. For example `IOQZ` can be mixed up with `1002`. When Tesseract is trained specifically on number plates, that's part of the data set. If you use a generic text datafile, you might want to add a post processing step to check that your output conforms to valid number plate patterns of letters and digits. You could also change `O` to `0` when it's in a digit position and to `D` when it's in a letter position.

Comment: Thanks for  your response.It seems like training Tesseract on Indian number plate will do the trick here.Will post updates once it is done.